# 20 minute timeout persists even when new user signs in

Tags: support, bug, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I just borrowed my coworkers workstation to ask a question on SO. He had just posted a question before I borrowed his workstation. After logging him out and and logging myself in and attempting to post,

I was given the 20 minute posting timeout:

[image]

Why does that appear when I attempt to post? Why should it matter that we are using the same machine and how does SO know? I tried in multiple browsers and with more of my colleauges and we have found that the behavior is reproducible.

Comment: Relevant blog: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/ - Basically, it's tracked by IP, not by user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you look at this post which may be a duplicate: [Bugging message "You can only post once every 20 minutes"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173677/bugging-message-you-can-only-post-once-every-20-minutes)

Basically, the reason for this time out is because, according to the top answer:

> "You are not supposed to ask every question that comes to mind even if
>   it is a good one."

It could be possible that you are asking too many questions at once. Stack overflow will also not allow you to post two questions in twenty minute intervals.

Hoped this cleared some questions you have.

Also, if you have not posted in 20 minutes then it may be possible that your colleague posted in that 20 minute time frame. This is because answers are:

> tracked at the IP address level, so multiple posts from the same IP,
>   even as different “users”, will still be blocked.